# Laravel Missing required parameters for Route: verification.notice

Tags: php, laravel

using Laravel 7.19

all my routes require a locale , including my Auth Routes to support different languages. And I've activated email verficitation for the users.

So once a user , that didn't verfiy his email , tries to open a part of my website that requires email verficitation Laravel automatically redirects them to this route : verification.notice

The Problem is that the route requires the locale parameter but I don't know how to pass the locale to the route. So I'm getting this error message

```
Missing required parameters for [Route: verification.notice] [URI: {locale}/email/verify].
```

Anyone knows the function that redirects me to the route : verification.notice ? Because I need to adjust or overwrite it so I can pass the locale parameter to it.

My web.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['setlocale'],'prefix' => '{locale}', 'where' => ['locale' => '[a-zA-Z]{2}']], function() {

Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);   
    
});
```

EDIT : Found Something usefule . Inside the File /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/EnsureEmailIsVerified.php

There's a function handle

If I add app()->getLocale() to it , the error message is gone. Looking like this now

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $redirectToRoute = null)
    {
        if (! $request->user() ||
            ($request->user() instanceof MustVerifyEmail &&
            ! $request->user()->hasVerifiedEmail())) {
            return $request->expectsJson()
                    ? abort(403, 'Your email address is not verified.')
                    : Redirect::route($redirectToRoute ?: 'verification.notice',app()->getLocale());
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

But I don't don't think you're supposed to make changes to /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/EnsureEmailIsVerified.php

How do I correctly overwrite this function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have to copy that middleware code and amend it that way. Simply copy the code of `Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailsVerified.php` from the `vendor` dir (which you should never edit itself by the way), create a new middleware in `App\Http\Middleware` and add it to `App\Http\Kernel`.

The `verification.notice` route you're seeing is added using `Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);` (its part a set of default routes for authentication/verification) as seen here: https://github.com/laravel/ui/blob/2.x/src/AuthRouteMethods.php#L84 (which is part of the `laravel/ui` package).

Comment: Thanks that worked . I created a new middleware by  php artisan make:middleware EnsureEmailIsVerified , then I copied the code from EnsureEmailsVerified into the new middleware and registered the new middleware in the kernel.php . Looks good.